# How to use a struct declared with 'constexpr' as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++14

Image you have a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b[2];
    int c;
} DataParameters;
```

In a specific situation, you know all these values at compile time:

```
constexpr DataParameters p = {
    .a = 5,
    .b = {3, 3},
    .c = 12
};
```

You then want to create a template function which uses the values of a, b, c. The following syntax is valid since the struct is declared as `constexpr`.

```
template<int A, int B_0, int B_1, int C>
void doSomething() {
    ...
}

doSomething<p.a, p.b[0], p.b[1], p.c>();
```

But let's say you have a struct that is much bigger and you do not want a giant list of template parameters. Is there any better way to it? I've tried the following, but get compiler errors:

```
template<const DataParameters& P>
void doSomething() {
    ...
}

doSomething<p>();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unrelated: Drop the C style type definitions.  If `DataParameters` is the type you want, do `struct DataParameters { ... };` and it's a type.

Comment: Works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/xt-5U-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++11 you can have `template <const DataParameters& P>` with objects that have static storage duration and either external or internal linkage.

Since C++17 you can have `template <const DataParameters& P>` with objects that have static storage duration (the linkage restriction was removed)

Since C++20 you can have `template <DataParameters P>` . The non-type parameter can be (since C++20):

> - a literal class type with the following properties:
>
>   - all base classes and non-static data members are public and non-mutable and
>   - the types of all bases classes and non-static data members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

```
struct DataParameters // don't use C style typedef
{
    int a;
    int b[2];
    int c;
};

template <const DataParameters& x>
void foo() {}

constexpr DataParameters gp{};

void test_ref_global()
{
    foo<gp>(); // ok since C++11
}

void test_ref_local()
{
    static constexpr DataParameters p{};    
    foo<p>(); // ok since C++17
}

template <DataParameters x> // ok since C++20
void bar() {}

auto test_val()
{
    constexpr DataParameters p{};
    bar<p>(); // ok since C++20
}
```

Comment: Reference template parameters have been allowed since C++98, although there might have been some restrictions on how they could be used.

Comment: @Brian I've tried on godbolt and this example doesn't compile on C++14. Maybe the ref type had to be a integer before?

Comment: @Brian I've done some more tests and edited the answer.

Comment: It seems that in C++98, the object had to have external linkage (I guess this implies static storage duration because `thread_local` didn't exist yet). In C++11, it had to have static storage duration and either external or internal linkage. In C++17, the linkage restriction was removed.

Comment: @Brian thank you. I've add this info to the answer. It is very helpful.